# saxparser java xml file with null element

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I am trying to parse an xml files using SAxparser. Everything works fine except the cases when an element tag in xml file contains null value. For example below xml element

```
<QuotaCode>
<null/>
</QuotaCode>
```

is parsed as 2 empty lines.
Below is code

```
public class ImportXML2 extends DefaultHandler {


    private StringBuilder elementValue = new StringBuilder();


    @Override
    // A start tag is encountered.
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {

        elementValue.setLength(0);


    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        switch (qName) {


            case "Total_number_of_packages": {
                System.out.println(elementValue.toString());
                break;
            }
            case "QuotaCode": {
                System.out.println("quote " + elementValue.toString());

                break;
            }
            case "office_code": {
                System.out.println(elementValue.toString());
                break;
            }


    } }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (elementValue == null) {

        } else {


            elementValue.append(ch, start, length);
        }
    }
}
```

result is(QuotaCode tag is present 2 times in xml doc ):

```
4
office_1
quote 

quote
```

Comment: Please share your saxhandler code. Your XML sample does not look like null values - it just contains an element with the name `null`

Comment: I added java code

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is wrong. SAX is firing the events other than you expect.

```
<QuotaCode>
<null/>
</QuotaCode>
```

When the SAX parser reads this document, it will fire

- startElement for `<QuotaCode>`
- characters for the linefeed (invisible)
- startElement for `<null/>`
- endElement for `<null/>`
- characters for the linefeed (invisible)
- endElement for `</QuotaCode>`

Maybe you expected `<null/>` to be the element text? Then you need to escape that data like so:

```
<QuotaCode>
&gt;null/&lt;
</QuotaCode>
```

Comment: Is there a way to parse null values as in this case?

Comment: Of course there is. You need to make up your mind how to represent null values. With the document you have null is an element, and when parsing you need to interpret that element as null. It is up to you.